# Rudin's definition of an ordered field

Tags: real-analysis, order-theory

As per [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3271321/rudins-definition-of-an-ordered-set) question here, Rudin's definition of an ordered set is completely equivalent to simply defining a (non-strict) total order on the set and then defining the corresponding strict total order.

My question is about whether we have the same result for ordered fields. That is, if Rudin defines an ordered field as

> An ordered field is a field $\mathbb{F}$ which is also an ordered set obeys the following two axioms:
> (1)For all $x,y,z$, if $y>z$ then $x+y>x+z$.
> (2) For all $x,y$, if $x>0$ and $y>0$ then $xy>0$.

This definition is meant to interact with his choice to define an ordered set in terms of a strict total order. I want to confirm that this new definition interacts nicely with the alternative definition in terms of a nonstrict total order given in the link. That is, if I were to define an ordered field as

> An ordered field is a field $\mathbb{F}$ which is also an ordered set obeys the following two axioms:
> (1)For all $x,y,z$, if $y\geq z$ then $x+y\geq x+z$.
> (2) For all $x,y$, if $x\geq 0$ and $y\geq 0$ then $xy\geq0$.

and then defined $>$ as in the link, I would recover Rudin's definition (and vice versa, if I use $<$ to define $\leq$)? I am getting lost in all the cases, and would frankly be happy even with a "yes/no" here. I do wish Rudin used the precise langugae of order theory etc. so that I don't get confused in the future, but oh well.

Comment: Why did you choose Rudin to read?

Comment: (This is a serious and not sarcastic question) Is there a better intro to analysis for someone with (I think) the requisite background? @WillJagy

Comment: That's why I brought it up. Your  physics questions suggest more of intro to differential geometry; that is, multivariable calculus, linear algebra, ODE. In general, I think there are book better for self study, you just might need to buy a few rather than download. Let me check again

Comment: Now I'm not sure. Are you studying on your own?

Comment: Yes, I am. And you're absolutely correct, my aim is eventually to be using math towards physics (and I would say I know enough "at the practical physicist's level"), but I'm interested in "starting again" but as a mathematician would. So I was going to read Rudin, then either Spivak or Hubbard, then maybe Lee or something like that (in terms of my analysis track -- and have something similar along an algebra track). If you have any suggestions I would be all ears! @WillJagy

Comment: alright. Well, noting a question of yours on Clifford algebras,  linear algebra   with a bit extra on quadratic forms always seems a good idea to me; my approach is number theoretic.. however, the basics of Lie algebras are just quadratic forms over the reals, familiarity ahead of time helps. Various groups   come from   all square matrices $X$   such that $X^T W X =  W$ for a fixed matrix $W$ of interest. And ODE  systems, if you can find a Jordan  form for some $A$  so that $A = QJ Q^{-1}$  then $e^{At}  = Q e^{Jt} Q^{-1}$  becomes easy

Comment: Yes, and to that end I’m starting to study from Hoffman and Kunze too! As far as I can tell it has a nice discussion of quadratic forms at the end? @WillJagy

Comment: I see, yes.  does groups... I would throw in  some things mostly discussed in terms of integers, Sylvester's Law of Inertia, generally reduction of (positive) forms. The calculation good to know is (repeated) completing the square, as in  given $$ H =  \left( 
\begin{array}{rrr} 
1 & 2 & 3 \\ 
2 & 5 & 12 \\ 
3 & 12 & 7 \\ 
\end{array}
\right) 
$$  construct  $$ Q^T D Q = H  $$

Comment: as in $$ Q^T D Q = H  $$

$$\left( 
\begin{array}{rrr} 
1 & 0 & 0 \\ 
2 & 1 & 0 \\ 
3 & 6 & 1 \\ 
\end{array}
\right) 
\left( 
\begin{array}{rrr} 
1 & 0 & 0 \\ 
0 & 1 & 0 \\ 
0 & 0 &  - 38 \\ 
\end{array}
\right) 
\left( 
\begin{array}{rrr} 
1 & 2 & 3 \\ 
0 & 1 & 6 \\ 
0 & 0 & 1 \\ 
\end{array}
\right) 
 = \left( 
\begin{array}{rrr} 
1 & 2 & 3 \\ 
2 & 5 & 12 \\ 
3 & 12 & 7 \\ 
\end{array}
\right) 
$$

Comment: Noted. Thank you very much for all your advice! @WillJagy

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The properties

(1) $y\geq z\implies x+y\geq x+z$

(2) $x,y\geq 0\implies xy\geq0$

clearly imply

(1') $y>z\implies x+y>x+z$ (because $x+y=x+z\implies y=z$)

(2') $x,y>0\implies xy>0$ (because $xy=0\implies x=0$ or $y=0$).

Conversely,

(1') $\implies$ (1) (because $y=z\implies x+y=x+z$)

(2') $\implies$ (2) (because $x=0$ or $y=0\implies xy=0$).